# Why do I still get child bounding boxes while I'm using RETR_EXTERNAL?

Tags: opencv

I'm struggling to get my contours right on a relative simple image.
I'm using RETR_EXTERNAL so if my understanding is well this setting should ignore any contour that's nested inside the parent contours, yet I still get child contours.

They are very noticeable in the last digit (the 8) and less noticeable in the first digit (upper left corner).

So what am I missing here? Or are there better ways to only get the parent bounding box?
Below slightly simplified script, mainly to show the problem.

```
img_tmp = sample.copy()
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(sample, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) # Original to RGB to distinguish bounding boxes

print('original image\n')
showImage(img_tmp,8,cmap=cm.gray)

# Threshold and get contours
img_tmp = cv2.threshold(img_tmp, 230, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
edged = cv2.Canny(img_tmp, 100, 250) #low_threshold, high_threshold
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")[0]

print('\nthreshed and edged image\n')
showImage(edged,8,cmap=cm.gray)
 
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour and isolate ROI
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    roi = img_tmp[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    # append to rgb original
    cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255 , 0), 2)

print('\nOuter boxes on original, but also inner...\n')
showImage(img_rgb,8)
```

[image]

Comment: You are finding contours, from two different functions assigned to the same output variable `cnts`. The output obtained from `imutils.grab_contours` overwrites the output from `cv2.findContours()`. Please comment out the line `cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)` and check again

Comment: thanks Jeru Luke, but I'm just 'overwriting' my cnts variable, so these are not really separate functions. It's quite common to use both together, first step find contours and next grab_contours, and commenting it out just returns an error.

Comment: My question is why find contours using `cv2` and `imutils`? You can just stick with `cv2` and it would give the desired output. Try commenting out the lines containing `grab_contours` and `sort_contours`, then check

Comment: Please share the source image so people can try it as their input

Comment: @Wokoman if you see your edge image closely you will notice some gaps between lines causing it to find unexpected contours. After finding the edges try morphological dilation operation and then proceed to find contours

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `RETR_EXTERNAL` is doing correctly what it is expected.

> CV_RETR_EXTERNAL retrieves only the extreme outer contours.

Actually, its is ignoring the inner contours which it has detected but the contours you want to ignore belong to a different segment. I mean new contours so `RETR_EXTERNAL` has nothing to do with them.

What you need to use is that `RETR_TREE`:

> RETR_TREE retrieves all of the contours and reconstructs a full hierarchy of
> nested contours.

With the help of this, you will be able to learn all of the contour hierarchy. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) is a well explained example of it.

Comment: Wokoman wants to **ignore** the inner contours (child). He is finding contours using two separate packages `imutils` and `cv2`, hence the result is getting messed up

Comment: @JeruLuke He is finding the contours but doesn't know the hierarchy construction. By knowing the hierarchy, the inner contours can be easily ignored. If you check the link I referred, will be more easy to understand

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk. He only want outer box not inner. The reasoning why is causing noising that why you getting inner box

Comment: more noising more boxing.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I think you are misunderstanding. First of all, some of those are not noise, for example '8' if you check inside of 8: small circles are not noise. What I mean is that if you know the hierarchy, you will be able to ignore child contours. This is my last comment to this answer, I believe I am clear :)